# Ubuntu Live USB saving/editing files on an External HDD

Tags: external-hdd

I'm using ubuntu-19.10-desktop-amd64 live USB to do some work on some files which are on an external USB HDD(not the same as the live image).
The problem that I have come across is the the changes look like they have been done (Renaming/resizing a .img), but when I reboot into Windows the files on the external HDD have not changed.
I've even downloaded files from the internet using Firefox on the live USB onto the external HDD, and when I reboot into Windows they are not there.

This is probably a beginners problem, but what have I done wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: 1. Did you run the command `sync` from a terminal window before you shut down the live system? 2. Did you save or copy the file on the external HDD? Copies on the live system's file system will not survive after shutdown or reboot. 3. Another and maybe more likely cause of the problem could be that **Windows is hibernated or semi-hibernated (alias fast startup)**. It means that whatever was the state in connected drives will be restored, when Windows wakes up from the [semi]hibernation. - When working with linux you had better turn off 'fast startup' in Windows.

Comment: Hi sudodus, Thanks for your reply. I think it was 3. I ejected the drive from Windows and shut down, booted up Linux and did the work, ejected the drive again and shut down, booted Windows and the work was there!

Comment: Thanks for telling us what was the problem :-)